# Why is my site trying to load the 32 bit aspnet_filter.dll even when 'enable32BitAppOnWin64' is set to False?

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-7-x64

I was developing an ASP.NET MVC web app on Windows XP and Visual Studio 2008 (using the Visual Studio web server). I recently installed Windows 7 64 bit Ultimate edition, IIS 7.5 and migrated my app using `appcmd`.

If I set the flag `enable32BitAppOnWin64 == false` on my application pool my application works fine. As soon as I set it to true (since I want it to run in 64 bit) it throws this exception:

[Screen Shot of error](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/cb0c835d4a.jpg)

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\\aspnet_filter.dll" failed
```

If I go and delete all ISAPI filters but leave `ASP.Net_2.0.50727-64` then this error goes away.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Who are you mohit are you indian Regard
Anirudha Gupta
http://anirudhagupta.blogspot.com

Comment: yes Anirudha, I am an Indian...

Answer (score 3):

Your key is in the path mentioned in the error:

> `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\\aspnet_filter.dll`

Notice there is an extra slash in the path.  At an elevated command prompt, navigate to `../Framework/v2.0.50272` directory and run the following command:

```
aspent_regiis -r
```

Alternatively, use IIS to modify the correct path of the filter.

So no magic dust needed...you just need to register the right path. :)

Comment: `aspnet_regiis -r` was not enough to fix this issue for me, but `aspnet_regiis -ua` (to uninstall ALL asp.net frameworks) and THEN the `-r` did work. You may have to fix the permissions on your `Temporary ASP.NET Files` folder after, though.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need some 64 bit ISAPI filters.

32 bit DLL's will not run on a 64 bit machine unless you sprinkle some magic pixie dust on them.  This is why the `enable32BitAppOnWin64` flag exists.

Set the flag to `true` and bask in the glory of the pixie dust.

Comment: But I think I have 64 bit ISAPI filter that is in my framework64 directory thats what being pointed by ASP.Net_2.0.50727-64

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the Handler Mapping `preConditions` for your site are a bit messed up. In IIS MMC browse to the site and open the Handler Mappings feature. In the Actions pane on the right, click the 'Revert To Parent' link.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this happen to a project deployment.
Changing the application pool for the website did the trick.
Found the answer on [Rick Strahl's weblog](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/Apr/04/Error-on-64-Bit-Install-of-IIS-LoadLibraryEx-failed-on-aspnetfilterdll)